# How to send a HashMap object via Jersey webservice framework?

Tags: hashmap, jersey

I have a simple hashmap calss that I want to send as JSON via Jersey. Does anyone have an example on how to perform such an operation , I have tried the following

```
package de.vogella.jersey.first;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import com.sun.jersey.api.view.Viewable;


// This method is called if XML is request
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })

public HashMap sayXMLHello() {

  HashMap map = new HashMap();
    map.put( new Integer( 2 ), "two" );
    map.put( new Integer( 4 ), "four" );
 return map;
 }

 // This method is called if HTML is request
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String sayHtmlHello() {
return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
    + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
}
}
```

and then the client

```
package de.vogella.jersey.first;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig; 
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;

 public class Test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
 Client client = Client.create(config);
  WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());
  // Calls the HashMap function       
  System.out.println( service.path("rest")
                                  .path("hello")
                                  .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                  .get(HashMap.class));

  // The HTML
   System.out.println(service.path("rest")
                                  .path("hello")
                                  .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                                  .get(String.class));

   }

 private static URI getBaseURI() {
 return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8080/de.vogella.jersey.first").build();
 } 

 }
```

once I deploy and call the client class , I get the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: GET       http://localhost:8080/de.vogella.jersey.first/rest/hello 
returned a response status of 500 Internal Server Error
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:686)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:507)
at de.vogella.jersey.first.Test.main(Test.java:25)
```

so any ideas on how can I send a HashMap object from a server to the client using Jersey? also I can't map the HashMap object to a POJO for not having a uniform structure (changes all the time)

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an old thread, answering so it might help someone.

Firstly, as mentioned by others, 500 error is most likely due to a problem in the server side code and nothing to do with the client.

To get a hashmap of type Map in the jersey client, use the GenericType as shown in the below code.

```
 ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
 Client client = Client.create(config);
  WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());
  // Calls the HashMap function       
  System.out.println( service.path("rest")
                                  .path("hello")
                                  .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                  .get(new GenericType<Map<String, String>>() {}));
```

Answer (score 0):

First figure out what the exception is on server side. That probably explains actual problem much better than posting questions before doing full trouble-shooting.

Comment: There aren't any errors on the server , this is all the client unable to send the correct code or the server unable to respond with the correct object.

Comment: I doubt that. 500 internal server error is typically sent in response to some piece of code catching an exception -- 5xx is never to be sent by server to indicate client sent wrong stuff. 4xx responses are for client errors. 5xx may of course be triggered by some unexpected stuff by client, and failure by server to do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the sample code to send  hashmap data through REST Service**

```
// CLIENT SIDE
package testHashMap;

import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;


public class SendHashMap extends HttpServlet{


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
        HashMapAcceptModel model = new HashMapAcceptModel();
        HashMap<String, String> positionList = new HashMap<String, String>();
        positionList.put("Key1", "Value1");
        positionList.put("Key2", "Value2");
        positionList.put("Key3", "Value3");
        model.setCompleteHashMapListList(positionList);
        try {
                Client client = Client.create();
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                String JSONData = mapper.writeValueAsString(model);
                System.out.println("JSON Object :"+JSONData);
                WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/RESTServer/gtl/json/metallica/JSONHashMapData");
                ClientResponse clientResponse = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, JSONData);
                System.out.println("Client Response :"+clientResponse.getEntity(String.class));         
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}

***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
// CLIENT SIDE
package testHashMap;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class HashMapAcceptModel {

public HashMap<String, String> completeHashMapListList = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public HashMap<String, String> getCompleteHashMapListList() {
        return completeHashMapListList;
    }
    public void setCompleteHashMapListList(HashMap<String, String> completeHashMapListList) {
        this.completeHashMapListList = completeHashMapListList;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "HashMapAcceptModel [completeHashMapListList="
                + completeHashMapListList + "]";
    }
}

***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
// SERVER SIDE

package testHashMap;


import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;



@Path("/json/metallica")
public class JSONService {

    public static HashMap<String, String> positionList = new HashMap<String, String>();


    @POST
    @Path("/JSONHashMapData")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response addLocationMap(HashMapAcceptModel hashmapModel){

        System.out.println("result :"+hashmapModel.getCompleteHashMapListList());
        String result = "Success";
        System.out.println("result :"+result);
        return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();
    }
}

***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
// SERVER SIDE

package testHashMap;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class HashMapAcceptModel {

public HashMap<String, String> completeHashMapListList = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public HashMap<String, String> getCompleteHashMapListList() {
        return completeHashMapListList;
    }
    public void setCompleteHashMapListList(HashMap<String, String> completeHashMapListList) {
        this.completeHashMapListList = completeHashMapListList;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "HashMapAcceptModel [completeHashMapListList="
                + completeHashMapListList + "]";
    }
}

***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
```

**You may need to use these library files**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Jersey does not provide a MessageBodyWriter for HashMap. You need to write a custom MessageBodyWriter.
Refer to [this link](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/REST-service-returning-Map-collection-td3713545.html)

Comment: Good answer, but you should post the answer in-line (in addition to pointing to the link) because Nabble tends to delete old posts over time.

Comment: Uh, that is not quite correct. JSON supports Maps just fine, out of the box. For XML, Adapter is needed as answer suggested. But writing a custom `MessageBodyWriter` is a total overkill.

Comment: @StaxMan Could you give some code example to send HashMap as json? I used the code in the question, then I got this exception: "A message body writer for Java class java.util.HashMap, and Java type class java.util.HashMap, and MIME media type application/json was not found"

Comment: You need to enable so-called "POJO mapping" as per [http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html], if the default JSON mapping does not support it.

Comment: @StaxMan Very thanks, I got it. PS: there is extra character ']' at the end of your link.

Comment: ah. it's a "feature" of SO wiki markup, does not include leading bracked. Glad it works tho!